# Why does my JTextArea not add in the line breaks from my String?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, line-breaks

I want a `JTextArea` to display the returned text when by user clicks a button, but although the actual string contains line breaks, the text area doesn't display them? Why?

[image]

[image: picture of unformatted text]

```
//when user clicks this button//
txtPizzaOrder.setText(newPizza.getInfo());

public String getInfo(){
    String sizeString=String.valueOf(this.size);
    String rtnStment="Size: "+sizeString+"\nCrust:"+this.crust+"\nSauce: "
            +this.sauce+"\nFirst topping: "+this.topping1+"\nSecond topping: "+
            this.topping2+"\nCost: "+this.getCost()+"\n------------------------";
    return rtnStment;
    }
```

Comment: `but although the actual string contains line breaks,` - how do you know? I don't see any debug code anywhere. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That is create a frame with a JTextArea and a JButton. When you click the button you append a hardcoded string containing line breaks. Get that working first. We can't tell why your code doesn't work because we don't know the value of all your variables etc.

Comment: Also, JTextArea does correctly display line breaks, I've done it many times.  So the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I've tested you code locally and it works, line breaks appear as they should. Error is probably somewhere else as @markspace pointed out. You need to show us more code.

Comment: it just doesn't work. Keeps outputting in a single line. no idea why

Comment: (1-) `no idea why` - so where is your [mcve]??? You have been told by 3 people that there is no secret to display line breaks in a JTextArea. The code you posted tells us nothing about your application. We don't have time to keep guessing it you don't have the time to create a proper "MCVE"!!!

Comment: it's because I've used a JTextField, not a JTextArea. Thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your picture, I see the text in the middle of the component, not the top.

This tells me you are probably using a `JTextField`, not a `JTextArea`.

If you need more help post a proper "MCVE". You have already been asked for this before.

Comment: Oh, it was that. Cheers.